# Collections form not handling when i submit form

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-3.3

my form 'Donacion' have a relationship with 'pajuela' OneToMany.
When i add 'Pajuela' with addTagForm, it is created, but if i submit the form and i do dump(formulario), the ArrayCollection 'pajuelas' is empty.

I have read the official documentation but not found my problem... 
This is the link: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/form_collections.html

This is my code:

```
# DonacionType

...
case 4:
                $builder
                    ->add('pajuelas',CollectionType::class, array(
                        'entry_type' => PajuelaType::class,
                        'entry_options' => array(
                            'tipo_sede' => $options['tipo_sede'],
                            'sede_id' => $options['sede_id'],
                        ),
                        'allow_add' => true,
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                        'by_reference' => false,
                    ))
                    ->add('observacionesPajuelas', TextareaType::class)
                ;
                break;
...

# PajuelaType

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tipo', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Completa' => 'Completa',
                    'Controles' => 'Controles'
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Pajuela::class,
            'tipo_sede' => null,
            'sede_id' => null,
        ));
    }

#Twig:

...
{% form_theme formulario _self %}

{% block _entidadbundle_donacion_pajuelas_entry_widget %}
    {% if form is defined %}
        {% if form.parent != null %}
            <div class="form-group {% if form_errors(form.tipo) %}has-error{% endif %} col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                {% if form_errors(form.tipo) %}
                    {{ form_label(form.tipo, 'pajuela.tipo' | trans) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.tipo, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control error'}}) }}
                    <label for="{{ form.tipo.vars.id }}"
                           class="error">{{ form_errors(form.tipo) }}</label>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form_label(form.tipo, 'pajuela.tipo' | trans) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.tipo, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
<div class="pajuelas" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(formulario.pajuelas.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% for pajuela in formulario.pajuelas %}
        <div class="row pajuela pajuela-persitida">{{ form_widget(pajuela) }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
...
```

I can not find what is the problem that I am having.

Comment: Please, can you post yout entities relations and your controller too ? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your child inputs are inside of the parent form in the HTML. It's strange to me that you are not receiving a field that it's created on the HTML. Also, try to dump and compare your Request object and your Form object; has the Request object these child inputs values?